Dart refactoring async function
New to Dart, apologies.
Given the original function:
  Future<void> setAppKeyClickEnabled(bool value) async {
    await _sharedPreferences.setBool(_appKeyClickEnabledKey, value);
    notifyListeners();
  }

I want to refactor it to:
  Future<void> set(String key, bool value) async {
    await _sharedPreferences.setBool(key, value);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> setAppKeyClickEnabled(bool value) async {
    set(_appKeyClickEnabledKey, value);
  }

Should the signature of setAppKeyClickEnabled now be:
 Future<void> setAppKeyClickEnabled(bool value) async

or
void setAppKeyClickEnabled(bool value) 

Or in other words, does the async keyword change the interface, or is it an implementation detail?
Bonus question (this is the first time I've looked at Dart), is there a way to make set private?

Bonus answer: certainly.  Anything beginning with underscore is library-private.

@RandalSchwartz Thanks! Ugly but effective.


Should the signature of setAppKeyClickEnabled now be:
Future<void> setAppKeyClickEnabled(bool value) async

or
void setAppKeyClickEnabled(bool value) 


If you want to preserve the original semantics where callers can wait for the operation to complete, the second version is completely unsuitable.  The first version is more correct, but your implementation is wrong.
Your choices should be either to await the Future returned by set:
Future<void> setAppKeyClickEnabled(bool value) async {
  await set(_appKeyClickEnabledKey, value);
}

or to return that Future directly:
Future<void> setAppKeyClickEnabled(bool value) {
  return set(_appKeyClickEnabledKey, value);
}

(The second version also could be written using arrow notation (=>), but I'm intentionally using an explicit return statement to make the difference with the first version clearer.)

Or in other words, does the async keyword change the interface, or is it an implementation detail?

async is an implementation detail and not part of the interface.  A function that returns a Future is asynchronous.  The async keyword merely enables the use of await as a keyword within the function and automatically wraps returned values in Futures.


A function that returns a Future is asynchronous.


@tpdi I don't understand your comment. Did you want me to emphasize that part?  If so, done.

Sorry, I thought I'd hit cancel on that comment.
